# Full Page Cache -> HTTP 500 on CMS Home -> Error in Module

Tags: magento2

We are using Magefans Blog Module.

When we are activating the Full Page Cache, it triggers a HTTP 500 on the CMS home page, where we are using a implementation of it.

Modules Block Code that triggers the error:

```
/**
 * Get Block Identities
 * @return Array
 */
public function getIdentities()
{
    return [\Magento\Cms\Model\Page::CACHE_TAG . '_relatedproducts_'.$this->getPost()->getId()  ];
}
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null in /home/customer00014/public_html/206/app/code/Magefan/Blog/Block/Post/View/RelatedProducts.php:135

Stack trace: #0 /home/customer00014/public_html/206/var/generation/Magefan/Blog/Block/Post/View/RelatedProducts/Interceptor.php(63): Magefan\Blog\Block\Post\View\RelatedProducts->getIdentities() 
#1 /home/customer00014/public_html/206/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Layout/LayoutPlugin.php(71): Magefan\Blog\Block\Post\View\RelatedProducts\Interceptor->getIdentities() 
#2 /home/customer00014/public_html/206/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(150): Magento\PageCache\Model\Layout\LayoutPlugin->afterGetOutput(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor), ' <script>\n ...'') 
#3 /home/customer00014/public_html/206/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array) #4 /home/customer00014/public_html/206/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(241): Mage in /home/customer00014/public_html/206/app/code/Magefan/Blog/Block/Post/View/RelatedProducts.php on line 135
```

In the specific .php-file theres a `->getPost()->getID()` call which triggers the error.

The question now is:

- why does the module calls a member function on null, and what does that mean?
- how can I fix this error? What would be the correct way to "get identitiers"?
- for what do I need Identities? Is it cache relevant?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by changing the files. I don't like this approach, but customers don't care for good code (or/and are not willing to pay for such :().

I basically just added a random number instead of getting the unique ID.

```
/**
     * Get Block Identities
     * @return Array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {   
        $random = rand(0,99999);
        return [\Magento\Cms\Model\Page::CACHE_TAG . '_relatedproducts_' . $this->getPost() . $random  ];
    }
```

Now Full Page Cache works. - however, now the blog pages throw errors.

Comment: Identities is used for the cache identifier, so by using a random number, you have essentially disabled the cache. (Other than when someone happens to get the same previously used random number). Since you mention this is a third party module, Id suggest raising this as a bug with them.